Fourier Transformation of the delta-function in l1-norm
I came across the following question and it seems to me, as if somebody has calculated it already.
Define the following d-dimensional distribution:
$$f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$$
with $$f(x)=\delta(t-||x||_1).$$
$t\in [0,\infty)$ is a positive constant and $||x||_1$ is the l1-norm (also known as the Manhattan-norm, Grid-norm, Mannheim-norm, etc.) of the d-dimensional vector x.
What is its d-dimensional Fourier transformation?
I know the answer for the euclidean norm. It can be calculated by transforming to spherical coordinates, calculating the angle integral and inserting the integral definition of the Bessel function. Any help or reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

So $f$ is "integrate over a square box of edge-length $2t$ (aligned with coord axes, centered at $0$"?

Not exactly. The case you are mentioning is the above problem with the $l\infty$-norm. Our n-dimensional box (unit sphere) has sidelength $\sqrt(2)$. And beware, there is a $\delta$-function inside. So we are looking at an integral over the surface of the n-dimensional unit-sphere in l1-norm.

Ah, thanks... but, then, is that reliably called "Manhattan norm"... which I would have thought was the $\ell^\infty$ norm...

Ok, am I still misguided... :) ... or is this now "integrate over surface of tetrahedron"? :)

Oop, "octahedron". :)

In the special case $n=3$ yes. To be more specific, call the octahedreon $O$ and its surface $\partial O$, then you can write the above Fourier transformation as $\int_{\partial O} d\omega{(\vec{x})}  : e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}$ . Here $d\omega{(\vec{x})}$ stands for the surface element of $O$ at $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}^3$. I omited the multiplicative constants incorporating $\pi$ as they are very dependent on your Fourier convention.

Ok, so it is "polytope dual of hypercube"... Thanks.

See section 3.10 of this book for a discussion of the Fourier transform of the $l_1$ unit ball ( solid region inside the $l_1$ unit sphere) in the 3D case.
By taking the derivative of dilates of this solid you can probably quickly deduce the formula for the Fourier transform of the $l_1$ unit sphere.
Another approach: look at each 2D face of the $l_1$ sphere separately, then applythe methods found earlier in that book.

Fourier analysis on polytopes

Wow! A very good source! Thanks! :)
